# Can User.Identity.IsAuthenticated within the Login method return true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have the following login method in my MVC project

```
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            if (_authenticationRepository.Login(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {                    
                var authenticationTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now,
                                                                         DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),
                                                                         model.RememberMe, "", "/");

                var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authenticationTicket));
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                UserContext.CreateUserContext();
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
```

UserContext.cs
This stores the user/permissions into a session.

```
    public static void CreateUserContext()
    {
        BuildUserContext(HttpContext.Current.User);
    }

    private static void BuildUserContext(IPrincipal principalUser)
    {
        if (!principalUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return;

        var user = _userAccountsRepository.GetUserByUserName(principalUser.Identity.Name);

        if (user == null) return;

        var userContext = new UserContext { IsAuthenticated = true };

        var siteUser = Mapper.Map(user);

        userContext.SiteUser = siteUser;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"] = userContext;
    }
```

I am aware that IsAuthenticated will only become true after a redirect. So within my login() method, is it possible to ensure that principalUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated will return true?

Or where else will be a good place to create the user context if not it the login method?

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. user logs in
2. if login is successful, query db for his roles/permissions and save them into a session so that I don't have to requery every time I'm checking if the user has access to a certain action.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like follows:

When user logs in for the first time, get user's role/permission details, serialize it and store it in the session. So as this session is in the memory, every time you want to check if user has permission to an operation deserialize this from memory instead of going to the database.